# Group fieldset element in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have html form and server side php. I want to group some form elements in HTML so it will appear in php as array like

```
<fieldset>
    <input name="xx[]" type="text" />
    <input name="yy[]" type="text" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input name="xx[]" type="text" />
    <input name="yy[]" type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

so it will appear in php array as

```
array (
    [0] => array(
        [xx] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )
        [yy] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )
    ),

    [1] => array(
        [xx] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )
        [yy] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )
    );
);
```

Comment: Why do you have four `xx` values in total but only two `xx[]` fields?

Comment: I am basically creating an array of fields.

Comment: The markup of the form is not relevant to how the data will be received by php. If you want a defined structure you only have the `name`-attribute to work with.

Comment: no, only for actual elements that will carry data. e.g. input, select, textarea and so on. Or to make it short, you can not use a fieldset to group data in any way for php.

Comment: I want to group them against fieldset so in  php I enumerate it.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain What you're trying to do (using a fieldset to group data) is simply not possible. You'll have to find a different approach.

Comment: if you can explain the different approach ?. Thanks